# StackOverflowError - Jaja

Tags: java, out-of-memory, stack-overflow, panel

I'm trying to do a simple code in Java : I have a class called "Bloc", which create blocks (square), which inside it I create a random width (largeur), and a random height (hauteur) between 2 ints, and I create a random number of blocks (nombreBloc). I also create an ArrayList to put every block in it, to see how much I have left.

So, I did a function called "insererBlocList" (insert the block into the ArrayList), which create "nombreBloc" (numberBloc) of blocks and put it into the ArrayList.

I've got a graphic interface, in which I have 1 panel for the windows, which inside it I have 2 other panels: One of them is to put every block I created into it.

Here is my problem, I've got a "StackOverflowError" inside my function "insererBlocList", which means there is an infinite loop, but after writing the path of code, I don't see where I did the mistake... Here is the code :

Bloc class:

```
public class Bloc extends JPanel{
    private int hauteur, largeur, nombreBloc;
    private boolean premierPassage = true;
    private ArrayList<Bloc> listeBlocRestant;
    private Random rand = new Random();

public Bloc() {
    this.hauteur = 10 + rand.nextInt(50 - 10);
    this.largeur = 10 + rand.nextInt(50 - 10);      
    listeBlocRestant = new ArrayList<Bloc>();
    if(premierPassage == true) {
        this.nombreBloc = 5 + rand.nextInt(30 - 5);
        insererBlocList();
    }
}

public ArrayList<Bloc> insererBlocList(){
    premierPassage = false;
    for(int i=0; i<nombreBloc; i++) {       
        Bloc bloc = new Bloc();
        listeBlocRestant.add(bloc);
    }
    return listeBlocRestant;
}
```

The GUI part of the panel block:

```
    private JPanel initPanelBloc() {
     panelBloc = new Bloc();
   }
```

Comment: Sorry if my english isn't that good, its not my main language :/

Comment: Well you create new `Bloc` objects inside `insererBlocList`, which is called by `Bloc`'s constructor, causing an infinite recursion. That's why you get the exception

Comment: You'd better make random instance static. It will take too much ram.

Comment: I did what @dhkim0800 told me to do, and I do not have the error. Since it is only used in the class Bloc, i should use static right ?

Comment: And also, thanks guys ;)

Answer (score 5):

Your `Bloc` constructor calls `insererBlocList()`, and `insererBlocList()` creates additional `Bloc` instances (for each of them the constructor calls `insererBlocList()`), which leads to an infinite chain of method calls, leading to `StackOverflowError`.

`insererBlocList()` probably shouldn't be called by the `Bloc` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You might thought premierPassage = false; will prevent method calling again. But insererBlocList() makes new instance of Bloc and this boolean value will be true again. Change code like this:

```
public class Bloc extends JPanel{
    private int hauteur, largeur, nombreBloc;
    private ArrayList<Bloc> listeBlocRestant;
    private Random rand = new Random();

public Bloc(boolean premierPassage) {
    this.hauteur = 10 + rand.nextInt(50 - 10);
    this.largeur = 10 + rand.nextInt(50 - 10);      
    listeBlocRestant = new ArrayList<Bloc>();
    if(premierPassage == true) {
        this.nombreBloc = 5 + rand.nextInt(30 - 5);
        insererBlocList();
    }
}

public ArrayList<Bloc> insererBlocList(){
    premierPassage = false;
    for(int i=0; i<nombreBloc; i++) {       
        Bloc bloc = new Bloc(false);
        listeBlocRestant.add(bloc);
    }
    return listeBlocRestant;
}
```

And change GUI part like this:

```
private JPanel initPanelBloc() {
     panelBloc = new Bloc(true);
}
```

Comment: In my GUI class, I put panelBloc as a panel, and then I'm doing  panelBloc = new Bloc(true) but should I put `private JPanel panelBloc; ` and `private Bloc bloc`, and then into initPanelBloc() : `panelBloc = new JPanel(); bloc = new Bloc(false)`

Comment: You don't need bloc field in GUI class.
And getPanelBloc method in your question doesn't return any JPanel. 
Change getPanelBloc method like this:


    private JPanel initPanelBloc() {

     panelBloc = new Bloc();

     return panelBloc;

   }